# Datatable to resize with Window In shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have an datatableoutput in a shiny page.The datatable has always 20 rows however I require it for it to re-size it's height according  to the size of the window it's in, either by just making it smaller or to reduce the number of rows of the datatable object in a single page with the ability to scroll to the others

I am not finding much info online on how to do this, so I need some tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the height op your datatable and the length of your page inside the `options` argument of your `renderDataTable` function. Example:

```
shiny::renderDataTable(
  DT_out, # datatable to return

  options = list(scrollY = '800px', pageLength = 1000) 
  # 800px is the height of the datatable
  # 1000 is just some big number to make sure that all rows fit on 1 page
)
```

More options can be found on https://datatables.net/reference/option/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew of that parameter. I set scrollY with the result of another function that receives the window height and now it dynamically adjusts to the height of the window.

Comment: Sounds like an even better solution. Feel free to extend / edit my answer if necessary